# How to return to last visited page of the website during next visit to the website

Tags: php, jquery, caching

How to return to last visited page of the website during next visit to the website?

The website do not have a login.  But it is a continous funnel of pages from 1-15, and pages datas are stored in sessions.  So need to return to the last visited page without losing the page datas

Comment: try to use Cookies to store some data on the client machine , and retrieve them back when visited later

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with cookies, both in the browser - and on the server.

PHP Example:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['checked_last_page'])){

//get last page visited
$lastPage = $_COOKIE['last_page'];

//expire cookie
setcookie('last_page', null, time() - 1000);

//forward to last page
header('Location: ' . $_COOKIE['last_page']);
exit(0);

}

//prevent doing redirect every time
$_SESSION['checked_last_page'] = true;

//set the last page in a cookie
setcookie('last_page', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], time() + 3600 * 24 * 31);

?>
```

You could do this with javascript too. In that case you'd have to set an additional cookie to mimic the behavior of a session cookie. This will ensure you don't do the redirect on page request that are part of an active session. (IE: The user visits a page and gets redirected - and gets redirected again)

Please let me know if you need a js example.

Comment: But the above code is not useful, as will redirect to the page but the session values wont carried thorugh

Comment: Can you elaborate? The session should carry though just fine..

Comment: The code does not work. It left the page in blank.

Comment: The code will not produce output - it will set a cookie for last_page and a session id. When the last_page cookie has value and the session key check_last_page is not set to true. A redirect header will be sent back to the value of the last_page cookie.